# SQL Server Agent cannot find Cert for backup job

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server Agent (2014) job for backups that executes a user stored procedure (USP). I can exec the USP manually and it works. When the Agent job runs I get an error

> user [myuser] Cannot find the certificate 'dbMasterEncryptionCert', because it does not exist or you do not have permission. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 15151)...

I have also tried

```
GRANT view definition ON CERTIFICATE::dbMasterEncryptionCert TO [myuser];
```

Does anyone here know the solution to this?

```
create master key encryption by password = '*';
create certificate dbMasterEncryptionCert
  with subject = 'Backup Encryption Cert'
      ,expiry_date = '20401231'
;

USP contains...
BACKUP DATABASE cpg
  TO DISK = @fullBackupFilePath
  WITH NAME = @backupSetName
      ,COMPRESSION
      ,ENCRYPTION(ALGORITHM = AES_256
                 ,SERVER CERTIFICATE = dbMasterEncryptionCert
                 )
      ,DESCRIPTION = @descriptionText
  ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the systems people were inadvertently prohibiting the Agent from running even though they that is was running. No wonder no one could figure out this problem.